# Why does localhost work but external URL doesn't in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat9

My tomcat server is configured as this:

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       address="192.168.122.15"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

When I try to access it via http://localhost:8080/{endpoint}, the operation works
When I use the external URL that's supposedly mapped to it: http://projecta.cave-gaming.com:8080/{endpoint}, it returns a 404 timeout error.

How do I map my tomcat server to the forwarded port so I can access it from an external URL?

Answer (score 0):

Have you bind the server to locahost?

You can configure this using the address attribute like described [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html)

You can do this in the server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" ...
```

If you omit the address attribute you are listening to all available addresses.

Comment: I deleted the address attribute and the external URL still times out.

Comment: Is your server reachable under this domain? Have you got a shell on the server then you could try to open a socket with `netcat -l 8080` and connect to it from another host with `telnet projecta.cave-gaming.com 8080`. Everything you type and send (with return) into telnet should appear on the console of the server

Comment: Sorry, I probably gave out the wrong details. I don't have a firm grasp on this right now. Do you mind if I post a new question and comment a link to it?